# Splitting data from URL?

Tags: php

Say my url is `site.php?id=X-34837439843`

How do i split it so I return

```
$table = "X";
$id = "X-34837439843";
```

Basically I'm using the same page to select from different tables, and the letter at the beginning of the ID represents which table, so I need to split the left side of the `"-"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple - use [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
list($table, $id) = explode('-', $_GET['id']);
$id = $table . '-' . $id;
```

[**codepad example**](http://codepad.org/BWwsgEm7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, after splitting the values are stored in array format in $regs

```
<?php
$str = $_GET['id'];

ereg("-",$str,$regs);
print_r($regs);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical method for portioning strings is:

```
$table = strtok($_GET["id"], "-");
$id = strtok("-");
```